# Roomba S9 - no data over serial connection

Tags: serial, roomba

Unlike other Roomba models, for the s9 there is little to no information available for setting up and using a serial connection to a Windows PC.

I've managed to get to the point where Putty serial can connect to the device on COM5 at 115200 baud. But with the Roomba appearing to be awake, no text comes across at all on the session, even when the device is put into diagnostics mode or rebooted.

Could this be a driver issue? Or, and indication that the motherboard is toast?

Tks

Comment: it could be anything

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Roomba S9+ doesn't support the [Open Interface spec](https://edu.irobot.com/learning-library/create-2-oi-spec).  So you can't control the robot through the USB port. And neither do any of the other latest generation of Roombas (i.e. the "i", and "j" series)

Only certain models of the 500, 600, 700, 800, and maybe "e" series robots have the serial port hardware and code support to make it "hackable". (And the existence of the port doesn't mean that the code supports it).  This feature was phased out a while ago.  So the older the robot, the more likely it will be to support the OI spec.

The proper way to control a Roomba is to use a "Create".  i.e. either a Create (antique), Create2 (recently retired), or [Create3](https://edu.irobot.com/what-we-offer/create3).

*Disclaimer: I work at iRobot where I am developing the next generation of consumer robots. However, my postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.*